# How to create a dataframe in pyspark from a dictionary which have different value size?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark

Assume that we have a python dictionary like this:

```
dict = {"person1" : (20, 17, 157, 31, 35), "person2" : (29 , 11) , "person3" : (200, 100 , 11)}
```

how to create a Dataframe in pyspark from this dictionary which has string keys and tuple with different sizes as its value?

my desired output is like this:

```
    key   |     value
-------------------------------------
 person1  |   (20, 17, 157, 31, 35)
 ------------------------------------  
 person2  |       (29 , 11)
-------------------------------------
 person3  |     (200, 100 , 11)
```

i tried to do that with this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
ddf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

but it raise a value error like this:

> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

can anybody advise me?

Comment: What is your expected output dataframe?

Comment: @Shu I edited my answer and show my expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **`from_dict`** + **`orient`** and then transpose the `df`

```
dict = {"person1" : (20, 17, 157, 31, 35), "person2" : (29 , 11) , "person3" : (200, 100 , 11)}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index').transpose()

#creating spark dataframe
sp_df = spark.createDataFrame(df).fillna({'person2':'','person3':''})

#cast all columns to int
ddf=sp_df.select([col(c).cast("int") for c in sp_df.columns])
ddf.show()
#+-------+-------+-------+
#|person1|person2|person3|
#+-------+-------+-------+
#|     20|     29|    200|
#|     17|     11|    100|
#|    157|   null|     11|
#|     31|   null|   null|
#|     35|   null|   null|
#+-------+-------+-------+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

```
dict = {"person1" : (20, 17, 157, 31, 35), "person2" : (29 , 11) , "person3" : (200, 100 , 11)}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index').fillna('').astype(str).transpose()

sp_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
ddf=sp_df.select([col(c).cast("int") for c in sp_df.columns])
ddf.show()
#+-------+-------+-------+
#|person1|person2|person3|
#+-------+-------+-------+
#|     20|     29|    200|
#|     17|     11|    100|
#|    157|   null|     11|
#|     31|   null|   null|
#|     35|   null|   null|
#+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you, but it was an example, and my dictionary has a lot of key, value pairs and I can't create Dataframe manually. So it is impossible to create with this instruction:

sp_df = spark.createDataFrame(df).fillna({'person2':'','person3':''})

Comment: Thank you guy. it work now. but as my dictionary is very large, a lot of null value produced because of difference in length. it is Ok but do you know another way to generate my second output desired?